# Microsoft Office Interop Excel 12.0 not working in IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, excel-interop

I am creating a pivot table excel sheet in my ASP .NET web application using Microsoft Office Interop Excel 12.0 components. It is creating the excel file correctly, when i run it from my Visual Studio 2008 in Debug/Release mode.

But when i deploy the solution in IIS 7, first i got some permission issues, which i resolved by giving permission in the DCOMCNFG file. Now i am getting the following error, when trying to open the Excel file:

> Microsoft Office Excel cannot open or
>   save any more documents because there
>   is not enough available memory or disk
>   space. • To make more memory
>   available, close workbooks or programs
>   you no longer need. • To free disk
>   space, delete files you no longer need
>   from the disk you are saving to.

These are the code which i used to open and close the excel application object

```
        xlApp.Visible = true;
        xlApp.UserControl = true;

        oSheet = null;
        oWB = null;
        xlApp.Quit();
        xlApp=null;
```

Comment: you should use the XML and packaging namespace to generate a OOML document on the server. Using Excel OM library is unsupported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please give up such an approach as soon as possible and consider Microsoft official suggestions,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757